# Clean URLs on OS X with MAMP using htaccess

Tags: macos, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

Last weekend I set up a new site at home on Windows (with xampp). Everything works, I get clean URLs (like http://mysite.com/page/about). Today I had to bring the files to my office where I'm using a Mac with MAMP and nothing worked. I change `AllowOverride` to `All` in the /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf file, and enabled `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`, with no luck. (Of course, I restarted MAMP)
But nothing happend. All of my webrowsers tell me nothing about the error. Just got the 'localhost:8888/' at the title.

I use these lines in .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(/)?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
   RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(/)?$ index.php?page=page&uri=$1
   RewriteRule ^work/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(/)?$ index.php?page=work&uri=$1
</IfModule>
```

What else I could do to make this working?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, I just find out it's working. The problem was with the included files. I used absolute path (like include '/template/sidebar.php') to php include function which does not work. I removed the first '/' and now it's good. I'm so lame..

Answer (score 0):

This allowed me to serve the file about.php in response to the request path /about:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(/)?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Note that on MAMP you have to put this in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(/)?$ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Putting that same block in httpd.conf did not work for me on MAMP.